# Thunderbird: Send Contact to friend via mail

Tags: email, thunderbird

I want to send a contact of my address book to a friend via mail.

I use thunderbird.

I could not find a way to do it. (Except taking a screenshot)

AFAIK this does not matter for this question: The contacts get synced via the sogo-plugin for thunderbird. Sogo connects to a custom owncloud server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible directly in Thunderbird.

But an extension exists that can do it: [MoreFunctionsForAddressBook](https://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/morecols-en.html)

> - send directly a contact as vCard attachment (from 0.3.4 version)

See [same question in Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1120198)

Comment: It **is** possible directly in Thunderbird, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to export the contact to a `.ldif` or `.vcf` file as described [here](http://its.isber.ucsb.edu/guides/how-import-and-export-your-address-book-thunderbird) and simply send this file.

For a single contact you need to add it to a new address list first. This way it's possible to export individual contacts:

- right-click on your address book and choose “New List”
- choose a list name like “export” and add the contacts you want to send

  - alternatively you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse drag to copy
    contacts from address books or other lists
- via “Extras”→“Export”, export the list in the desired format
- attach the file to your mail

Comment: this will send the whole address book.

Comment: @Rovo It is possible to just export a list, I added instructions to send a single contact using this method.

Comment: Of course there are many workarounds like that. But I'm pretty sure, that OP wants an easy solution, not a workaround.

Comment: @RoVo That's not a workaround, it's just using the builtin functionality – not everybody likes to cram his installation with addons. However, I agree that the addon solution is a viable way as well, I think this question is well-answered offering these two alternative ways.

Answer (score 1):

1. In **Thunderbird** go to **Tools-->Ad-ons**
2. Click on **Extensions**
3. Type **CardBook** into the search text-box
4. Click the **Install** button in the CardBook column
5. After the CardBook extension installs, restart **Thundebird**
6. In **Thunderbird** go to **Tools-->CardBook**
7. When CardBook first starts, it will want to import your address book(s).
8. Once your address book(s) have been imported, click on the address book name in the left-hand column.
9. Right click on the address book entry you want to share, and select **Share by email**